# Extjs4 MVC save item to server

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am working with Extjs4.1 MVC. What I am trying to do is save some data to the server but I do not know the proper format or how I should go about submitting the data to the server.
Here is what I am thinking but I do not believe the Ajax call should be in the controller, it should be in the model or in the store file?

method in my controller:

```
    submit: function(value) { 
    data = {"id": 100, "tdt": "rTk", "val": "445"}   // test data
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://test.myloc.com/providerSvc/dbproxy.php',
        params: {
          'do':'insert',
          'object': 'stk',
          'values': data
        },
        success: function(response){
            alert('response.responseText);
        }
    })
   }
```

My store:

```
Ext.define('STK.store.Stack', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'STK.model.Stack',
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
          read: 'http://test.myLoc.com/providerSvc/dbproxy.php?do=get&object=stack'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        successProperty: 'success'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json'            
    }
}
});
```

my model:

```
Ext.define('STK.model.Stack', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: ['id', 'tdt', 'val']
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`store.sync()` works only when the endpoints for GET and POST are same.

What you can do is, for GET,
set the extraParams by concatenating to the URL or by creating an object like

```
extraParams[urlKeys] = paramObject[urlKeys];
store.getProxy().setExtraParams(extraParams);
```

then,

```
Store.getProxy().setUrl(StoreUrlForGET);
Store.load({
callback : function(rec, operation, success) {
if (success) {}
else {}
});
```

and for POST write an AJAX request as,

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url : StoreURLForPOST,
method : 'POST',
jsonData : Ext.JSON.encode(YourPostData),
success : function(response, request) {},
failure : function(response, request) {}
});
```

for this AJAX request you can,

```
Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({
"TokenId" : TokenValue
});
```

All of this code goes into your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think the store is the proper place to make the ajax call.

You can "save" one record by adding it to the store, and then calling the "sync()" function.

Something like this (beware: code not tested):

```
    var store = Ext.create("STK.store.Stack");


    var record =  Ext.create("STK.model.Stack");

    record.set(xvalues);
    record.isDirty = true;
    record.setDirty(true);  // I don't know if this line is required

    store.add(record);


    store.sync({
        success: function(batch, options){

          alert("OK!")                

        },
        failure: function(batch, options){ 
           alert("failure!")
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes that makes sense but how do you send that data to the server to update the db? Notice that I have to post with a different url:

http://test.myLoc.com/providerSvc/dbproxy.php?do=insert&object=stack&values={data here}'

Comment: Well, that depends on what is "listening" on the server! ExtJS just performs a standard HTTP method (usually a POST). 

On your server you must have something to handle that POST, like PHP, or ASP.NET, etc.

You can use a Firefox or Chrome developer tools to see exactly what the browser is sending to the server. You'll see that it is just plain text, with some specific format. Server must interpret that text and do something with it.

Comment: In my case it's do = insert